# How to get Date in format of 01 Aug 2017?

Tags: android

I have an app in which i have to get last seven days from current date which is working fine but i am getting date in format of dd-MM-yyyy but i want get it as 01 Aug 2017. How do i do that pls let me know.

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    Log.e(TAG,"Current date:::"+dateFormat.format(date));
    String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date);


    DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
    String sevenDaysBefore = dateFormat1.format(cal.getTime());
    Log.e(TAG,"seven days before::"+sevenDaysBefore);
```

Comment: http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/code-base/java-date-format-2/

Answer (score 1):

Change Formater to `("dd-MMM-yyyy")`

```
DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
String sevenDaysBefore = dateFormat1.format(cal.getTime());
Log.e(TAG,"seven days before::"+sevenDaysBefore);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dateformation() {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy");
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    String strDate = dateformate.format(currentDate.getTime());
    System.out.println("Date is :  " + strDate);


    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy");

    sdf.applyPattern("dd MMM, yyyy");
    Date x = new Date(currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900,
            currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(x));

}
```